# initializing array element to NULL

Tags: c, arrays, null

How to initialise an element of array to NULL.For example if I have 
char *array[10];
I want last element to be NULL, so that I can pass this array to execv

Comment: Just set it to 0. NULL should be used with pointers.

Comment: sorry I edited. it meant to be pointer

Comment: @chris: the part about `execv` suggests that it should actually be `NULL`, but the OP doesn't realize that they're handling an array of pointers.

Comment: @larsmans, I haven't used that. I figured it needed a null terminated string :p

Comment: @chris: you're both right, `execv` takes a `const char*` as well as a `char**`.

Comment: @nzrksafina: can you show us your current code? It's not clear what the problem is.

Comment: To do literally what you asked, set the last element of a 10-element array to a null pointer, `array[9] = 0;`. But I suspect that's not all there is to it.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

To initialise an array of `char*` to all `NULL`s:

```
char* array[10] = { NULL }; /* The remaining elements are implicitly NULL. */
```

If you want to provide initial elements for `execv()`:

```
char* array[10] = { "/usr/bin/ls", "-l" }; /* Again, remaining elements NULL. */
```

or if you wish to omit the dimension from the array declaration:

```
char* array[] = { "/usr/bin/ls", "-l", NULL };
```

Answer (score 1):

`NULL` is nothing but : `#define NULL (void*) 0 UL`
The `NULL` you are talking about is `nul` character which is `'\0'`

see `man execv` page or other exec processes .. it's actually take variable number of arguments

Comment: ..and what ascii value does the '\0' have?

Comment: @duedl0r That would be 0

Comment: It's not standard but you can say `null` There are 3 types, 1st is : NULL pointer already know, 2nd is NUL character which is '\0' it's ASCII is 0. And the 3rd is actual zero which is decimal 0 having ASCII 48

Comment: @dueld0r: since character constants in C have type `int`, the character constant `'\0'` means exactly the same thing as the integer constant `0`. Some people prefer it, because it reminds them that they're using characters. Personally I can't help but read it as "the `int` value of the character whose integer value is 0" (in C++ it's, "the `char` value of the character whose integer value is 0" and means the same as `char(0)`).

Comment: @Omkant Although it seems obvious what you are trying to express, its formally not correct: `NUL`/`'\0'` is the ASCII character which is represented by the decimal value `0`. There is no ASCII character `0`. Decimal `48` being ASCII character `'0'` is a different story.

Answer (score 1):

execv takes an array of `char *`, not an array of `char`.

```
char *const parms[] = {"abc", "-a", "pqr", NULL};
```

Answer (score -3):

IF your array is object,String,Char if you declare it will be automatically null

eg.

```
Oject [] myarray=new Object[10];
```

at any place of array is null

Comment: OP's question is referencing the C language, not an Object Oriented Programming (OOP) language like Java. In C, one of the closest things to an object is `struct`,  which doesn't seem strongly related to OP's question, at least to me.